# Getting Pandas DataFrame label indices from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am figuring out how to get the indices of labels in [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) `DataFrame` based on column values. I have the following `DataFrame`:

```
d = {'col1': ['label1', 'label2', 'label3'], 
     'col2': ['label2', 'label3', 'label1'], 
     'col3': ['label2', 'label1', 'label3'],
     'col4': ['label3', 'label1', 'label2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

which formats as:

```
     col1    col2    col3    col4
0  label1  label2  label2  label3
1  label2  label3  label1  label1
2  label3  label1  label3  label2
```

I am trying to get it to the following form:

```
       label1 label2 label3
col1      0      1      2
col2      2      0      1
col3      1      0      2
col4      1      2      0
```

This tells the index of each label in the corresponding column in the original DataFrame `df`. For example, in `col3`, the indices of labels 1-3 are 1, 0 and 2, respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html#pandas.DataFrame.T) and then [`argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.argsort.html):

```
res = pd.DataFrame(df.T.values.argsort(1),
                   columns=np.sort(df.iloc[:, 0].values),
                   index=df.columns)

print(res)

      label1  label2  label3
col1       0       1       2
col2       2       0       1
col3       1       0       2
col4       1       2       0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.stack().reset_index(name='v').pivot('level_1','v','level_0')
print (df1)
  v        label1  label2  label3
level_1                        
col1          0       1       2
col2          2       0       1
col3          1       0       2
col4          1       2       0
```

Or [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.reset_index().melt('index').pivot('variable','value','index')
print (df1)
 value     label1  label2  label3
variable                        
col1           0       1       2
col2           2       0       1
col3           1       0       2
col4           1       2       0
```

Last step is remove index and columns names:

```
df1.index.name = None
df1.columns.name = None
print (df1)
      label1  label2  label3
col1       0       1       2
col2       2       0       1
col3       1       0       2
col4       1       2       0
```